# Can't find the main PostgreSQL client header, libpq-fe.h. Are you sure the libpq headers are installed correctly, and that we've got the right path

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am trying to compile the `libpqxx` on **Windows** , following the instruction `https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/blob/7.8.0/BUILDING-configure.md`

Here is my command:

`/d/libpqxx-7.8.1/configure CXXFLAGS=-O0 CXX=g++ --with-postgres-lib="D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\lib" --with-postgres-include="D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\include" --prefix="D:\libpqxx-7.8.1\libpqxx" --enable-shared  CXXFLAGS="-std=c++17"`

In this command, I have added the path of `libpq-fe.h`. But the error still exists:

```
configure: error:
Can't find the main PostgreSQL client header, libpq-fe.h.  Are you sure the
libpq headers are installed correctly, and that we've got the right path?
```

Comment: Try the path slashes the other way e.g. `"D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/include"`